# Insert PHP file in functions.php then echo variables from that file in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-shortcode, require-once

After trying to find a solution to this, I've decided I'm not bright enough. So, please help.
Here the idea: have a file (ip.php) detect the visitors' country/city, call it once in functions.php (or header.php), then echo/print variables from this ip.php file into the other Wordpress theme files (for example footer.php).
This is the ip.php content:

```
<?php
function getUserIP()
{
    if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"])) {
              $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"];
              $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"];
    }
    $client  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    $forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    $remote  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    if(filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
        $ip = $client;
    }
    elseif(filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
        $ip = $forward;
    }
    else
    {
        $ip = $remote;
    }
    return $ip;
}
$user_ip = getUserIP();
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use GeoIp2\Database\Reader;
$cityDbReader = new Reader('/html/nocache-ip/GeoLite2-City.mmdb');
$record = $cityDbReader->city($user_ip);
$country = $record->country->name;
?>
```

Using the following in the header.php works fine for the header:

```
require_once( ABSPATH . '/nocache-ip/ip.php' );
echo "\nYou came from $country\n";
```

The country, city names are displayed. But when trying to use the same code again in the footer.php, it doesn't work (*Undefined variable: country*).

So this is the issue. **How can I make echo/print the visitor's country in other parts of the theme, while calling the ip.php only once?**
I've read about having to make all this into a function, then add it to functions.php somehow and then calling the variables with country(); unfortunately this is above my head.

Answer (score 0):

You can use include so that your function is available, example: `<?php include 'yourfunctionpage.php';?>`

In your functions.php you declare a variable:

```
$var = 'yourvariable';
```

then in anotherfile.php you can use the variable from functions.php like this:

```
include 'functions.php';
echo $var;
```

Comment: I've used include, include_once, require, require_once and the results is the same. Echoing $country in any other file than the one it includes ip.php does not work because the variable ($country) is undefined.

Comment: In which file is your function defined? lets say its in "functions.php". Then you should include functions.php in your new page and you should be able to use its variable. @JohnnyBravo I also updated my answer to give you an example of what I mean

Comment: it is in header.php, as explained in the description

Comment: @JohnnyBravo then include your header file using same method as I showed above